# implicitly declared special member functions

Tags: c++

There are four special functions fundamentally implicitly declared.

1. Default constructor
2. Default destructor
3. Default assignment operator
4. Default member-wise copy operator

Question:

If any one of them is defined by user, [eg: Destructor ] rest of the three functions will not get declared. Is that the correct?
 or 
it is applicable only to default constructor, and copy Constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare your own constructor, of **any** type (including copy constructor), then the **default constructor** is no longer implicitly declared. The rest are (unless you have declared one of them yourself).

However, if you find yourself declaring any one of 2, 3 or 4, then you most likely should declare the other two, even if the compiler implicitly declares them. This is known as the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

**Edit** in C++11 there are also implicitly declared *move copy constructor* and a *move assignment operator*, so the rule of three becomes the rule of five.

Comment: Make that "rule of five" with the introduction of move semantics.

Comment: @ManofOneWay of course it is, thanks! I can't believe I got three upvotes with that mistake.

Comment: "However, if you find yourself declaring any one of 2, 3 or 4, then you most likely should declare the other two". ->  If i declare any one of 2 or 3 or 4, then  rest of the two functions declared implicitly?

Comment: @Whoami yes they get implicitly declared, but the rule of three says that you should probably declare and implement your own.

Comment: @Whoami yes, if the user provides a copy constructor, then the default constructor is no longer implicitly declared. But the default constructor is no longer implicitly declared if the user declares **any** constructor, single or multi-argument. But the other constructors are still implicitly declared (although I am not 100% sure that applies to the C++11 move constructors).

Answer (score 5):

There is very informative and concise table at the end of this page by Howard Hinnant https://howardhinnant.github.io/classdecl.html

[image]

Comment: The graphic does not include info what the coloring means. I'd assume that red means "this happens, but it's usually not good and you should declare those yourself".

Comment: Specifically it means that the behaviour is deprecated since C++11, because as you inferred it's usually the wrong behaviour, so you should declare those.

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not have to explicitly declare the others just because you are declaring one. However, if you declare one of `2)`, `3)`, `4)`, you probably need to declare the others as well.

This is called [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). I believe it's called [the rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)  in C++11.

Comment: I think they've settled on ["rule of five"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11).

Answer (score 1):

If you define your own `Foo()`, the default `~Foo()` will still be declared, and vise versa. Same with the assignment operator and the copy constructor. Just remember, that if you define a constructor with arguments, you lose the default constructor. You have to do this to get one too:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(); //Declares a default constructor.
  Foo(int);
}
```